# Public DNS (IPv4) on alibaba cloud as use for other clouds?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

When I tried the free aws account, I have used the Public DNS to test my website (something like http://ec2-10-2-127.us-wes-2.compute.amazonaws.com/).

How can I get that using alibaba cloud ?

I found out this Link, but I didn't know how to get the public dns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alibaba Cloud Free trial ECS provides you with a public IP address. You can directly enter this IP in the browser to access your ECS instance. And if a web server like Nginx or Apache already running on the ECS instance and listening on port 80, you will be able to access your website.

BTW, Alibaba cloud ECS does not provide FQDN as AWS does.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok for you to use Alibaba Cloud DNS service. please follow the below guideline.

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/product/162402.htm

Alibaba Cloud DNS is a secure, fast, stable, and reliable authoritative DNS service. It helps enterprises and developers convert human-readable domain names into machine-readable IP addresses and then routes user requests to required website or application servers.